# How To Know If Dispatch Is Success or No In Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

So i already create the createMonsterStart and it will hit my API, my API is returning response code, and I want to alert success when the response code is 00 otherwise it will alert failed, how can i achieve that? here is my code:

```
const onSubmitHandler = () => {
  dispatch(createMonsterStart(monster))
  if(dispatch success){
    alert("success")
  }else{
    alert("error")
  }
}
```

And here is the redux saga code:

```
export function* createMonsterAsync({ payload: { monster } }) {
try {
  const user = yield select(getUser)
  const a = yield call(createMonster, user.user.token, monster)
  if (a.error) {
    yield put(createMonsterFailure(a.error))
    return false
  }
  const monsters = yield call(fetchMonsterAsync)
  yield put(createMonsterSuccess(monsters))
} catch (error) {
  yield put(createMonsterFailure(error))
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264017/react-redux-sagas-wait-for-a-saga-to-set-state

Comment: Add 2 additional parameters to your createMonsterAsync; onSuccess and onFailed. Pass whatever function you want with those 2 parameters and call them accordingly in your saga.